# Opening an image from a url in PHP[closedd]

Tags: php, image, extract

So I am trying to open an image from a URL using PHP but nothing seems to work. Here is my code. All i get is a blank box and I have tried with multiple links.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iMAJ.png) is what I get for any URL I use. Any ideas? Any responses are greatly appreciated

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
$p = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0094/2252/products/KithxAspenUltraBoostMidMulti-1_grande.jpg?';
$a = file_get_contents('$p');
echo $a;

?>
```

Comment: put that in some html and use `$a` in src ..

Comment: its an https so might be gives problem.....what error come?

Comment: I uploaded a picture. I get no error but theres no image. Just a tiny blank gray box @Jagtap

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `single qoutes`, in this case, because then your $p var *get litteral value* (just string :$p)
, you need this:

```
$a = file_get_contents($p);
```

(or double quotes).

Comment: I tried with no single quotes and also tried double quotes but neither had any effect

Comment: @JosePaz, are you trying from localhost, or online server? If this doesn't work, and it must work (tested), probably file_get_contents function is dissalowed on your server.

Comment: Its from localhost but i have allowed file_get_contents. I figured out a different way to get the picture to show up by converting to base64 coding